# What scale do you play over V7#9?

Tags: theory, chord-theory, jazz

In Mark Levine's *Jazz Theory* Book (section about tritone substituion), he says (paraphrased):

```
When the tritione substitution contains the 7th in the melody, 

you can add a #9 to the chord.
```

So a `Bb7` is replaced with a `E7#9`, where the `#9` is a `G`, major 3rd `G#`

Which would give you V7#9 a tritone up from the `V` in a `ii - V - I`.

I don't remember him talking about a mode this chord belongs to?

Is this the same as a `V7b9` using the `half-whole dim` scale?

What mode best fits this chord? Assuming "best fit"  is similar to playing Mixolydian on a Dominant Seventh.

Comment: Chromatic, it's got every note.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `E half-whole diminished` scale would work, but it's probably not the first choice unless you're specifically looking for that diminished sound. I'll stick with the example you described, where the progression `B♭7 – E♭Maj` is being played with a tritone substitution: `E7♯9 – E♭Maj`. Here are some chords that will sound good over `E7♯9`:

- `E Altered` scale: `E F G A♭ B♭ C D E` (this is the 7th mode of F melodic minor)
- `E Phrygian ♭4` scale: `E F G G♯ B C D E` (this is the 3rd mode of C harmonic major)
- `E Diminished` scale: `E F G A♭ B♭ B D♭ D E`
- `E Phrygian Dominant` scale: `E F G♯ A B C D E` (this is the 5th mode of A harmonic minor)
- `E Mixolydian ♭9` scale: `E F G♯ A B C♯ D E` (this is the 5th mode of A harmonic major)

The [harmonic major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_major_scale) scale is less common but has some really cool sounds. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8kmjbPR2Mis) provides a nice overview of the harmonic major modes.

Something worth pointing out is that, if you want, you can think of the `E Altered` scale as `B♭ lydian #4` (the fourth mode of `F melodic minor`). These two scales have the exact same notes. Another thing to mention is that the `E Mixolydian ♭9` scale & the `E Phrygian Dominant` scale don't contain the `♯9` note (i.e., don't contain a `G`). These scales would still sound good over `E7♯9`, but if you're sticking strictly to the scale then you'll be missing that `♯9`, which is probably in the melody if `♯9` is written into the chord. One simple solution is simply to add the `♯9` into the scale whenever you want to reference the `♯9` note. Doing this could be important if you want to reference the melody. The `♯9` often appears in chord symbols *because* the note is being played in the melody.

All of these scales would also sound great over an `E7♭9` chord.

Comment: There's something wrong with the notes of the "E Diminished" scale in your list. It starts as a half-whole but ends as a whole-half. Apart from that, the diminished scale (whole-half) is not really a great choice over a dominant chord (with the same root) because it has a *major* seventh instead of a b7.

Comment: Thanks @MattL for pointing out the typo! I've fixed it and it should now correctly show the dominant seventh.

Comment: I've also edited to add the phrygian dominant scale, which might be another option (though it doesn't have the `♯9`).

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the Jazz minor (which is the same as the ascending Melodic Minor, the Major scale with a b3) of a half step above, it always works (e.g. for a D7+9 play an Eb Jazz Minor where the root of your chord is the major 7 of the scale).  Let me know what you think.